# HashMap to Java Class Object

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, hashmap, jackson

On server I have something like this

```
public class Instrument {
    private String myPropOne;
    private String myPropTwo;
    private String myPropThree;
    public String getMyPropOne() {
        return myPropOne;
    }
    public void setMyPropOne(String myPropOne) {
        this.myPropOne = myPropOne;
    }
    public String getMyPropTwo() {
        return myPropTwo;
    }
public void setMyPropTwo(String myPropTwo) {
    this.myPropTwo = myPropTwo;
}
public String getMyPropThree() {
    return myPropThree;
}
public void setMyPropThree(String myPropThree) {
    this.myPropThree = myPropThree;
    }
}
```

and on Browser side it a map is to be sent

```
{ my_prop_one : 'val1', my_prop_two : 'val2', my_prop_three : 'val3'}
```

One way is to create define toMap() methods and put all the properties one by one and do the same when it is coming from UI-side something like fromMap()

Now question is I want write some common function

```
set('my_prop_one', 'val2')
```

so that it will look up the instance and set correct value, i will be extending this class to create more instruments types with different properties
I can do this using annotations

```
public class Instrument {
    private String myPropOne;
    private String myPropTwo;
    private String myPropThree;
    @KeyMap(value="my_prop_one")
    public String getMyPropOne() {
        return myPropOne;
    }
    @KeyMap(value="my_prop_one")
    public void setMyPropOne(String myPropOne) {
        this.myPropOne = myPropOne;
    }
    @KeyMap(value="my_prop_two")
    public String getMyPropTwo() {
        return myPropTwo;
    }
    @KeyMap(value="my_prop_two")
    public void setMyPropTwo(String myPropTwo) {
        this.myPropTwo = myPropTwo;
    }
    @KeyMap(value="my_prop_three")
    public String getMyPropThree() {
        return myPropThree;
    }
    @KeyMap(value="my_prop_three")
    public void setMyPropThree(String myPropThree) {
        this.myPropThree = myPropThree;
    }
}
```

I will have to write annotations twice. is there any better way to do this? Some thing like I add annotations on properties and getter/setter get somehow linked and can be used to extract properties, some way to create a hashMap?

JsonUtil I am already using
 gives me this out put

```
{ myPropOne : 'val1', myPropTwo : 'val2', myPropThree : 'val3'}
```

But again setter/getter for one property? how to do that?
**EDIT 3 :**

```
@JsonAnyGetter & @JsonAnySetter
```

like explained in example [here](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/07/entry_458.html)  But they work on  only map not real properties which is my requirement.

Comment: Is it a requirement that you roll your own solution to this? Frameworks like Jackson (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) and Gson (https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) exist to do this for you.

Comment: No there's no such requirement, I am already using JackSon. But how do I make my getter/setter work and mapping of fields?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried https://github.com/flori/json-utils?
it contains functionalists you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Jackson (per your comment) then something like this should handle it all for you automatically:

```
public class Instrument {
    @JsonProperty private String myPropOne;
    @JsonProperty private String myPropTwo;
    ...
}
```

Then you can use the ObjectMapper class to create your JSON by calling:

```
Instrument instrument = new Instrument();
instrument.setMyPropOne("val1");
// set other values

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
// configure mapper if needed
mapper.writeValueAsString(instrument);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still could not find the answer, because it does not completely solve my problem, i need setter/getters, jackson provides something JsonAnyGetter & JsonAnySetter, but still not what I am looking for. because these work for additional map, not for properties.

Comment: One more try, perhaps @JsonValue is what you need? It lets you define a method that returns a Map which is then used instead of fields to create your JSON object. It's sort of like toString() but toJSON() instead. http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonValue.html